# Why is my Regex search yielding more than expected and why isn't my loop removing certain duplicates?

Tags: python, regex, duplicates, append, python-re

I'm working on a program that parses weather information. In this part of my code, I am trying to re-organise the results in order of time before continuing to append more items later on.

The time in these lines is usually the first 4 digits of any line (first 2 digits are the day and the others are the hour). The exception to this is the line that starts with `11010KT`, this line is always assumed to be the first line in any weather report, and those numbers are a wind vector and NOT a time.

You will see that I am removing any line that has `TEMPO` `INTER` or `PROB` at the start of this example because I want lines containing these words to be added to the end of the other restructured list. These lines can be thought of as a separate list in which I want organised by time in the same way as the other items.

I am trying to use Regex to pull the times from the lines that remain after removing the `TEMPO` `INTER` and `PROB` lines and then sort them, then once sorted, use regex again to find that line in full and create a restructured list. Once that list has been completed, I am sorting the `TEMPO` `INTER` and `PROB` list and then appending that to the newly completed list I had just made.

I have also tried a `for` loop that will remove any duplicate lines added, but this seems to only remove one duplicate of the `TEMPO` line???

Can someone please help me figure this out? I am kind of new to this, thank you...

This ideally should come back looking like this:

```
ETA IS 0230 which is 1430 local

11010KT 5000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN004
FM050200 12012KT 9999 LIGHT DRIZZLE BKN008 
TEMPO 0501/0502 2000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN002
INTER 0502/0506 4000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN008
```

Instead of this, I am getting repeats of the line that starts with `FM050200` and then repeats of the line starting with `TEMPO`. It doesn't find the line starting with `INTER` either...

I have made a minimal reproducible example for anyone to try and help me. I will include that here:

```
import re

total_print = ['\nFM050200 12012KT 9999 LIGHT DRIZZLE BKN008', '\n11010KT 5000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN004', '\nINTER 0502/0506 4000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN008', '\nTEMPO 0501/0502 2000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN002']

removed_lines = []
for a in total_print:  # finding and removing lines with reference to TEMPO INTER PROB
    if 'TEMPO' in a:
        total_print.remove(a)
        removed_lines.append(a)
for b in total_print:
    if 'INTER' in b:
        total_print.remove(b)
        removed_lines.append(b)
for f in total_print:
    if 'PROB' in f:
        total_print.remove(f)
        removed_lines.append(f)

list_time_in_line = []
for line in total_print: # finding the times in the remaining lines
    time_in_line = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', line)
    list_time_in_line.append(time_in_line.group())
sorted_time_list = sorted(list_time_in_line)

removed_time_in_line = []
for g in removed_lines:  # finding the times in the lines that were originally removed
    removed_times = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', g)
    removed_time_in_line.append(removed_times.group())
sorted_removed_time_list = sorted(removed_time_in_line)


final = []
final.append('ETA IS 1230 which is 1430 local\n')  # appending the time display
search_for_first_line = re.search(r'[\n]\d\d\d\d\dKT', ' '.join(total_print))  # searching for line that has wind vector instead of time
search_for_first_line = search_for_first_line.group()

if search_for_first_line:  # adding wind vector line so that its the firs line listed in the group
    search_for_first_line = re.search(r'%s.*' % search_for_first_line, ' '.join(total_print)).group()
    final.append('\n' + search_for_first_line)

print(sorted_time_list)  # the list of possible times found (the second item in list is the wind vector and not a time)
d = 0
for c in sorted_time_list:  # finding the whole line for the corresponding time
    print(sorted_time_list[d])
    search_for_whole_line = re.search(r'.*\w+\s*%s.*' % sorted_time_list[d], ' '.join(total_print))
    print(search_for_whole_line.group())  # it is doubling up on the 0502 time???????
    d += 1
    final.append('\n' + str(search_for_whole_line.group()))

h = 0
for i in sorted_removed_time_list:  # finding the whole line for the corresponding times from the previously removed items
    whole_line_in_removed_srch = re.search(r'.*%s.*' % sorted_removed_time_list[h], ' '.join(removed_lines))
    h += 1
    final.append('\n' + str(whole_line_in_removed_srch.group()))  # appending them

l_new = []
for item in final:  # this doesn't seeem to properly remove duplicates ?????
    if item not in l_new:
        l_new.append(item)
total_print = l_new

print(' '.join(total_print))
```

**//////////////////////////////////////////EDIT:**

I had asked this recently and got an excellent answer to my problem from @diggusbickus. I have now hit a new problem with the sorting in the answer.

Because my original question had only one type of weather line (beginning with the letters 'FM') in my `data['other']`, the `lambda` with the `split()` was only looking at the first item of the line `[0]` for the time.

```
data['other'] = sorted(data['other'], key=lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

Which is where the time is located (in previous question it was `FM050200` where 05 is the day and 0200 is the time). That works very well for when there are lines beginning with `FM`, but I have realised that occasionally lines like this exist:

```
'\nBECMG 0519/0520 27007KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT020 BKN030'
```

The time in this style of line is the FIRST 4 digits located at index [1] and is in a 4 digit format instead of the 6 digit format line in `FM050200`. The time in this new line is `05` as the day and `19` as the hour (so 1900).

I need this style of line to be grouped with the `FM` lines, the problem is that they don't sort. I am trying to find a way to be able to sort the lines by time regardless of whether the time is on the `[0]` index and in 6 digit format or on the `[1]` index and in 4 digit format.

I will include a new example with a couple of small changes on the originally answered question. This new question will have different data as the `total_print` vairable. This is a working example.

I essentially need the lines to be sorted by the FIRST 4 digits of any line, and the results should look like this:

```
ETA IS 0230 which is 1430 local

FM131200 20010KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT006 BKN010 
FM131400 20010KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT006 BKN010 
BECMG 1315/1317 27007KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT020 BKN030 
TEMPO 1312/1320 4000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN007
```

NB. The `TEMPO` line is supposed to stay at the end, so don't worry about that one.

Here is the example, thank you so much to anyone who helps.

```
import re

total_print = ['\nBECMG 1315/1317 27007KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT020 BKN030', '\nFM131200 20010KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT006 BKN010', '\nFM131400 20010KT 9999 SHOWERS OF LIGHT RAIN SCT006 BKN010','\nTEMPO 1312/1320 4000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN007']
data = {
    'windvector': [], # if it is the first line of the TAF
    'other': [], # anythin with FM or BECMG
    'tip': []  # tempo/inter/prob
}

wind_vector = re.compile('^\s\d{5}KT')
for line in total_print:
    if 'TEMPO' in line \
            or 'INTER' in line \
            or 'PROB' in line:
        key = 'tip'
    elif re.match(wind_vector, line):
        key = 'windvector'
    else:
        key = 'other'
    data[key].append(line)

final = []
data['other'] = sorted(data['other'], key=lambda x: x.split()[0])
data['tip'] = sorted(data['tip'], key=lambda x: x.split()[1])


final.append('ETA IS 0230 which is 1430 local\n')

for lst in data.values():
    for line in lst:
        final.append('\n' + line[1:])  # get rid of newline

print(' '.join(final))
```

Comment: That certainly doesn't look like an MRE. In any case, you should never remove items from something you're iterating over.

Comment: So how would you do it different? Can you help provide a solution then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just sort your data into a dict, you're always creating lists and removing items: it's too confusing.

your regex to catch the wind vector catches also `12012KT`, that's why that line was repeated. the `^` ensures it matches only your pattern if it's a the beginning of the line

```
import re

total_print = ['\nFM050200 12012KT 9999 LIGHT DRIZZLE BKN008', '\n11010KT 5000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN004', '\nINTER 0502/0506 4000 SHOWERS OF MODERATE RAIN BKN008', '\nTEMPO 0501/0502 2000 MODERATE DRIZZLE BKN002']

data = {
    'windvector': [],
    'other': [],
    'tip': [] #tempo/inter/prob
}

wind_vector=re.compile('^\s\d{5}KT')
for line in total_print:
    if 'TEMPO' in line \
            or 'INTER' in line \
            or 'PROB' in line:
        key='tip'
    elif re.match(wind_vector, line):
        key='windvector'
    else:
        key='other'
    data[key].append(line)
        
data['tip']=sorted(data['tip'], key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
print('ETA IS 0230 which is 1430 local')
print()
for lst in data.values():
    for line in lst:
        print(line[1:]) #get rid of newline
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, it works super well thank you. Please see my edit as you maybe have an answer for me......

Comment: that's not how things go. this is a different question, ask a new one